# (1) Find a closed-form solution for this recurrence relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics

(1) Find a closed-form solution for this recurrence relation: $a_n=2a_n−1−n+1$ with $a_1=2a_n=2a_n−1−n+1$ with $a_1=2$

(2) Prove that your closed-form solution is correct

So far, my answer is (1) Solve with substitution.

$$n=\frac{2a-1}{ a-1}$$

(2) It is correct as $a_2 = 2a_1-2+1$   $a_2=4 -2+1 =3$

$2(2)-1/2-1 = 3$.

Is this correct???

Comment: do you mean $$a_n=2a_{n-1}-n+1$$?

Comment: yes, my apoligies with the notation.

Answer (score 1):

Let us make the problem more general considering $$a_n=\alpha\, a_{n-1}+\beta\, n+\gamma\tag 1$$ and, as Felix Marin did, let $$a_n=b_n+ \delta\, n+ \epsilon\tag 2$$ Replacing in $(1)$, you then arrive to $$b_n-\alpha\,b_{n-1}=(-\alpha  \delta +\alpha  \epsilon +\gamma -\epsilon )+n (\alpha  \delta +\beta
   -\delta )\tag 3$$ To simplify the problem, set $$-\alpha  \delta +\alpha  \epsilon +\gamma -\epsilon =0\tag 4$$ $$\alpha  \delta +\beta
   -\delta =0\tag 5$$ $(4)$ and $(5)$ are two linear equations in $\delta$ and $\epsilon$. These are easy to solve and the solutions are (provided $\alpha \neq 1$) $$\delta=-\frac{\beta }{\alpha -1}\qquad , \qquad \epsilon=\frac{\gamma -\alpha  (\beta +\gamma )}{(\alpha -1)^2}$$ and the only problem to solve is $$b_n=\alpha\,b_{n-1}\implies b_n=c_1 \alpha ^{n-1}\implies a_n=c_1 \alpha ^{n-1}-\frac{\beta }{\alpha -1} n+\frac{\gamma -\alpha  (\beta +\gamma )}{(\alpha -1)^2}$$ $c_1$ being defined by the condition.

In your case $\alpha=2,\beta=-1,\gamma=1$ the above give $\delta=1$, $\epsilon=1$

Answer (score 0):

solve the equation $$a_n=2a_{n-1}$$ with the ansatz $$a_n=C\cdot q^{n}$$ with $$C=const.$$ and then try to find a special solution of $$a_n=2a_{n-1}-n+1$$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{a_{n} = 2a_{n - 1} - n + 1\,,\ a_{1} = 2}$

Let $\ds{a_{n} = b_{n} + \mu n}$. Then,
\begin{align}
b_{n} + \mu n = 2b_{n - 1} + 2\mu n - 2\mu - n + 1 =
2b_{n - 1} + \pars{2\mu - 1}n - 2\mu + 1
\end{align}
Choose $\ds{\mu = 2\mu - 1\quad\imp\quad\mu = 1\quad\mbox{and}\quad
b_{n} - 2b_{n - 1} = -1\quad\mbox{with}\quad b_{1} = 1}$.

---

Also,
\begin{align}
b_{n} - 1 & = 2\pars{b_{n - 1} - 1} = 2^{2}\pars{b_{n - 2} - 1} = \cdots =
2^{n - 1}\pars{b_{1} - 1} = 0\quad\imp\quad b_{n} = 1\,,\forall\ n \geq 1
\end{align}

---

$$
\color{#f00}{a_{n}} = b_{n} + n = \color{#f00}{n + 1\,,\quad n = 1,2,3,\ldots}
$$